# redux-saga never resolve with takeEvery effect

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to apply server-side rendering to existing react application. And facing a problem my root saga never ends.

```
function* actionExecutor() {
  const apiMethod = api.apiMethod;
  try {
    const response = yield call(apiMethod);
    if (response.success) {
      yield put(successAction(response.body));
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

function* someSpecificSagas() {
  yield takeEvery('ACTION_NAME', actionExecutor);
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    fork(...),
    ...,
    fork(someSpecificSagas),
  ]);
}

store.runSaga(rootSaga).done.then(() => console.log('saga complete'));
```

What am I doing wrong here and how to make root saga to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was I needed to dispatch END action to store then sagas starting to resolve;